# Angular Mat-Slider Min Max Problem On Float Numbers Have 'e'

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-slider

I'm trying to use mat-slider on numbers like;
min: -1.7976931348623157e+308, max: 1.7976931348623157e+308 step:0.01
But it doesn't behave as it is. The number gets changed just between min and max, not steps 0.01.

```html
<mat-slider *ngIf="valueType === 'slider'" [formControlName]="name" [id]="name" [step]="0.01" [min]="minValue" [max]="maxValue"></mat-slider>
```

Comment: You should include some code. Can you add the template code inside the body of your question?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I added. I didn't add it at first because it was simple and straight.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is exactly, but I suggest to work with smaller numbers instead. If you remove the *e+308* part, it looks like the slider works. After you got your value from the slider, just multiply it back with *1e+308* to get your desired value.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu thanks for the solution this seems can be implemented.